# Installing PhoneGap getting "error not found: git"

Tags: node.js, git, cordova

When installing PhoneGap with node.js, I get the above error.  I running the Node.js command prompt as Admin.  Here is the full list of errors from the log:

```
370 error not found: git
371 error Failed using git.
371 error This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
371 error Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.
372 error System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
373 error command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "phonegap"
374 error cwd C:\Windows\System32
375 error node -v v0.10.28
376 error npm -v 1.4.9
377 error code ENOGIT
378 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I have added my path to git.exe to the nodevars.bat file and when I type 'git' in the node.js cmd screen, I get the useage response (proving that git is in the path).

This is a brand new machine, so I'm probably overlooking something, but I can't quite figure out what.

Edit: more info - I'm using Windows 8.1 and I am using the "Node.js command prompt" (the title on the window).  I'm following the instructions from here: http://phonegap.com/install/

When I type git at the prompt I get:
    C:\Windows\System32>git
    usage: git [--version] [--help] [-c name=value]
               [--exec-path[=]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
               [-p|--paginate|--no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
               [--git-dir=] [--work-tree=] [--namespace=]
                []

Comment: Why are you using Git in the "node.js cmd screen"(you mean the node REPL?)?Open the command line (not the node.js one) and type git there,show us the result.

Comment: Nope, I definitely am using the node.js command screen. (Please see edit).  The git command is being called by the npm, I think. I'm pretty sure the npm is trying to download files using git and, for some reason, it's failing inside the script.

Comment: The node command screen wont install anything, it only evals code.You have to install it from the command line,ie cmd.exe

Comment: Ah, yes, you are correct.  Unfortunately, tho', I get the same error even from a "regular" cmd prompt. If I type `git`, I can see the usage output.  It's acting the same as from in the node.js prompt.

Comment: What are you typing to install phonegap?

Comment: npm install -g phonegap

Comment: I found it... I'm not really sure why this worked.  I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After rebooting and trying other thing, it just seemed that some part of the npm script wasn't finding git.  I opened the Git Shell and ran the command from there.  It installed.

Comment: how it's possible to open git shell?

Comment: @Daniel - I'm running GiyHub 2.1.1 on Windows 8.1 (with Classic Shell).  It installed a 'GitHub, Inc' item in my Programs menu. Under that is a shortcut to Git Shell. Another idea: try "C:\Users\[you-user]\AppData\Local\GitHub\GitHub.appref-ms".  This opened the Git shell for me.  HTH!

Answer (score 5):

I had with same problem, but I installed a previous version that it´s working. Try this:  npm install -g phonegap@3.4

Answer (score 0):

I could install it also, after installing git on my cygwin. cigwin/bin is in my PATH, so after that installing phonegap@3.5 from windows' cmd wasn't a problem.